# How to convert docx file to .chm using Python

Tags: python

I want to convert contents(text, images, links) of docx file to .chm file using Python. Can anyone please suggest how to do.

I tried to read the docx file content using `docx2txt`
 https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt  package. But I am not sure how to read the images and links in the file. 
Can someone please suggest how to read each content separately and convert it to .chm file.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe warned this has a learn curve.

You need to extract all sections from your Word document into clean HTML files including the graphic files.

Please try to [Save Word as HTML](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.thewindowsclub.com/extract-images-word-document/amp&ved=0ahUKEwjRnsSnwJvWAhWkd5oKHU3tA38QFggeMAE&usg=AFQjCNHSXwAvBCaq_fyoVOJ0N7bMNdjB1Q&ampcf=1). But I think this don't make clean HTML.

You need the Microsoft Htmlhelp  compiler for creating Chm files. I recommend using a converter tool or a Help Authoring Tool (Hat) for your task.

Search by Google for such tool "DoctoChm" and give it a try for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to convert some resumes to plain text. There are any number of use cases for wanting to extract readable text from binary formats.

you can see the url 'http://davidmburke.com/2014/02/04/python-convert-documents-doc-docx-odt-pdf-to-plain-text-without-libreoffice/'